# How to set field level security on new field with simple_salesforce

Tags: custom-field, python, field-level-security, simple-salesforce

I'm working in Python with the simple_salesforce library.

I can create new fields on my Account and Contact objects, based on info in [How to update object description using simple_salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/373958/how-to-update-object-description-using-simple-salesforce).

Basically, I'm doing the following for each of my new fields:

```
    mdapi = sf.mdapi
    custom_object = mdapi.CustomObject.read("Account")
    custom_object.fields = [
        {"fullName": "my_field__c", "label": "My Field", "type": "Text", "length": 20},
    ]
    mdapi.CustomObject.upsert(custom_object)
```

This works, except that I need to set the field level security to "visible" manually.
How can I do this in my code too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
profile = sf.mdapi.Profile('Profile Name')

profile.fieldPermissions = (
    [{
        "field": "Account.my_field__c",
        "readable": True,
        "editable": True,
        "hidden": False
    }]
)

query_response = mdapi.Profile.update(profile)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: To help the next person reading this: note that names of common profiles include "Admin" and "Standard".
I found some useful related notes at https://www.salesforcehacker.com/2013/09/whats-in-name-well-apparently-lot.html and https://roycon.com/who-can-see-what-in-salesforce/

Comment: (or anyone else)...
Some things that are still not clear to me, which would help flesh out this answer:
- Where is the best documentation re profiles, permissions, and managing them via simple_salesforce?
- I'm an Admin user on this project.  Adding readable/editable to the Admin profile gave my code these abilities, as expected. I thought adding readable and editable to Standard instead would have also given me these rights (assuming Admin has a superset of Standard's powers). But this did not work. Why?
- Is there an API that returns all of the profile names?

Comment: Glad it worked! I referenced the simple_salesforce GitHub repo readme and the SF Metadata documentation profile -https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm - and then just a lot of trial and error.  The Admin profile is a separate profile, not a superset.  To get a list - check out the repo readme section on Metadata - you're after the describe method.